# Is Typescript able to force the domain of a value to be within a set of key names declared in the same object?

Tags: typescript

I am quite new to Typescript and I am really appreciating its type checking capabilities.

I need to understand if with its capabilities it is possible to check at compile time if the domain of a value is within a set of key names declared in the same object?

The following example will help to clarify my question.
I have these object and type definitions:

```
type ElemField = { name: string }
type Elem = Record<string, ElemField>

type Relation = { path: string[] }

type MySchema = {
    elem: Record<string, Elem>,
    relations: Record<string, Relation>
}

const test: MySchema = {
    elem: {
        elem1: {
            prop1: { name: 'string' },
        },
        elem2: {
            prop2: { name: 'string' },
            prop3: { name: 'string' },
        },
        elem3: {
            prop4: { name: 'string' },
        }
    },
    relations: {
        relation1: {
            path: ['elem2', 'elem1'],
        },
        relation2: {
            path: ['elem3', 'elem1'],
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if it possible to check at compile time if the `path` array contains values only within the domain of the keys of the `elements` key at root level.

I cannot understand if with the usage of `keyof`, generics, or some other Typescript features it is possible to define such relation.

EDIT: Thanks to `Shahriar Shojib` I got a first valid solution.
But I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this without employing a function, but simply specifying the type for the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there are better ways to achieve this, but this should work for your use case.

```
type ElemField = { name: string }
type Elem = Record<string, ElemField>

type Relation <T> = { path: T[] }

type MySchema<T extends Record<string, Elem>>  = {
    elem: T,
    relations: Record<string, Relation<keyof T>>
}



function createSchema<T extends Record<string, Elem>>(schema:MySchema<T>) {
    return schema;
}

createSchema({
    elem: {
        elem1: {
            prop1: { name: 'string' },
        },
        elem2: {
            prop2: { name: 'string' },
            prop3: { name: 'string' },
        },
        elem3: {
            prop4: { name: 'string' },
        }
    },
    relations: {
        relation1: {
            path: ['elem2', 'elem1', 'elem5'], // error since it does not exist
        },
        relation2: {
            path: ['elem3', 'elem1'],
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It works, but it is no 100% what I was looking for.
Is it possible to achieve this without employing a function?
Why do I need `createSchema` function in order to do that?
Why using your type definition with generics can't I do this `const test: MySchema<Record<string, Elem>> = { ... }` and having Typescript compiler signalling the error?

Comment: I don't think that's possible since you're saying the record's keys are string and when it's inferred it will be treated as string[], I believe it can be done with the infer keyword in typescript, but I haven't dug deep into it yet sorry.

Comment: Total aside, this is an amazing answer, just because this can even work at all!

Comment: @Shahriar Shojib Ok, I get it. If I am right you are saying that the only way to avoid the usage of the function would be doing `const test: MySchema<{ elem1: {...}, elem2: {...}, elem3: {...} }> = { ... }`.
The `createSchema` function would do it programmatically for me since typescript in this case has more information about T.
Is it right?

Comment: yes exactly, after some digging, there is a PR in typescript repo that allows generic to be used just like using it with a function, but it's not merged yet.